# Show that if $I$ is an interval and $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $I$, then $f(I):=\{f(x):x\in I\}$ is an interval.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $I$ is an interval and $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $I$, then $f(I):=\{f(x):x\in I\}$ is an interval.

I dont't know how to start, can someone please give me ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What can you say about $f(I)$ if it is not an interval?

Comment: **Hint** Use the intermidiate value theorem.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, is "$f(I)$ is continuous" trivial?

Comment: $f(I)$ is not a function, so it is not continuous. What did you mean to ask?

Comment: I mean is "$f(I)$ is connected" trivial?

Comment: It depends on whether you understand the definition. Why don't you ask it as a new question? (Though most likely it has been asked already.)

Comment: Anyway, what you really want is that in $\mathbb R$ the notions of connected and interval coincide.

Comment: @ awllower: How will you use the intermidiate value theorem?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ For some reason there is no indication that you have left a message for me, so I did not notice it. Sorry for that. And I meant to say that, if $f(a)\le \gamma\le f(b)$, then there is $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=\gamma$. This show that $[f(a),f(b)]$ is an interval. Of course the above is only a special case, but the general is not very far from it I suppose. Regards.

Comment: @ awllower: You mean $f(a):=\inf(f(I)),f(b):=\sup(f(I))$?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Yes, that is one way you handle the general case. In view of the great answer by copper hat, this becomes quite obvious now. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$I$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, hence $f(I)$ is connected. The connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

To see why $f(I)$ is connected, suppose $f(I) \subset U \cup V$, with $U,V$ open and disjoint. Then $f^{-1}(U)$, and $f^{-1}(V)$ are disjoint and open (since $f$ is continuous), and we have $I \subset f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V)$. Since I is connected, we must have $I \subset f^{-1}(U)$ or $I \subset  f^{-1}(V)$, and hence we have either $f(I) \subset U $ or $f(I) \subset V $. It follows that $f(I)$ is connected.

To see why an interval is connected, suppose $I \subset U \cup V$ with $U,V$ disjoint and open. Suppose $x,y \in I$, with $x \in U, y \in V$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x <y$. Now let $t = \sup \{\tau |\, [x,\tau] \subset U \}$. (Since $y \in V$, we must have $t \le y$.) If we have $t \in U$, then since $U$ is open, we must have $t+\delta \in U$ for some $\delta>0$, which contradicts the definition of $t$. Hence we must have $t \in V$. However, since $V$ is open, we must have $t-\delta \in V$ for some $\delta>0$, which again contradicts the definition of $t$. Hence if $x \in U$, we must have $y \in U$, and so
it follows that $I \subset U$. Hence $I$ is connected.

To see why a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval: Suppose $C$ is connected, but not an interval. Then we must have $x,y,z$ such that $x,y \in C$ and $z \notin C$. It follows that $C \subset (-\infty,z) \cup (z, \infty)$, the union of two open disjoints sets. However this immediately contradicts the fact that $C$ is connected. Hence $C$ must be an interval.

**Addendum**: Proof using the intermediate value theorem:

First, note that an interval is a set $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the property that if $x,z \in I$, with $x\le z$, then if $y$ is a number such that $x \le y \le z$, then we have $y \in I$ as well.

Suppose $f(I)$ is not an interval, then we must have $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that $\alpha<\beta < \gamma$, $\alpha, \gamma\in f(I)$ and $\beta\notin f(I)$. Hence we must have $a,b$ such that $\alpha = f(a), \gamma= f(c)$, and $f(a) < \beta < f(b)$. From the intermediate value theorem we have some $b \in [a,c]$ such that $f(b) = \beta$, which is a contradiction. Hence $f(I)$ is an interval.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks for catching that. Not sure why I assumed it was closed...

Comment: So the only thing pending now is why being connected and being an interval coincide.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: You are making me earn my pay :-).

Comment: @ copper.hat: Actually this question is in an exercise after the intermediate value theorem, can you please tell me how to apply it? Or should I ask it as another question?

Comment: :-)${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I added a proof using the intermediate value theorem.